# How to fix Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, unity-game-engine

I brought a native plugin from unity assets store. However when i build in IOS it generated a lot these error:

Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
  "__ISN_GetPendingNotifications", referenced from:

"__ISN_CancelUserNotifications", referenced from:

"__ISN_RequestPermissions", referenced from:

"__ISN_CancelUserNotificationById", referenced from:

"__ISN_ScheduleUserNotification", referenced from:

"__ISN_FT_AppOpenshortcutItem", referenced from:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)